# Meteor React - Publish / Subscribe not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I can't figure out where I am going wrong, but here is my code in imports/api

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

Blogposts = new Mongo.Collection('blogposts');

if (Meteor.isServer) {

  Meteor.publish('allBlogposts', function () {
    return Blogposts.find({});
  });
}
```

And in in my frontend jsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';

Blogposts = new Mongo.Collection('blogposts');

 export default class BlogPage extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  subscription: {
    blogposts: Meteor.subscribe('allBlogposts')
  }
}
}
```

From there though, I can't seem to access any data from my database if I console log, I added two records to the database from the server.

How can I get this working for a simple console log that returns those two documents?

Comment: Are you explicitly importing this code from `imports/api`?

Comment: @styx yes, that's where I have the Mongo collection.

Comment: Where is the code that access this `Blogposts` collection?

Comment: Can you show us how you are testing for data? Where are you accessing and rendering it?

Answer (score 0):

```
# api    
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export default Blogposts = new Mongo.Collection('blogposts');

if (Meteor.isServer) {

   Meteor.publish('allBlogposts', function () {
      return Blogposts.find({});
   });
}
```

Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

#import your api
import { Blogposts } from "whatever/the/dir/is.js

class BlogPage extends Component {

# Everything here

}
#you write this function outside your component
BlogPage.propTypes = {
  currentUserPost: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
export default withTracker(()=>{
  Meteor.subscribe("allBlogposts");
  return {
    currentUserPost: Blogposts.find()
  }
})(BlogPage);
```